# Get child record values in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to get the list of accounts and child object contact in the datatable ( HTML table).

I'm looking to achieve the nested table in LWC:

**ForEx:**

Account Name      Phone   
Test                              2323232 
      ContactFirstName    LastName    Phone 
                laae        reee     131321312

Displaying the data table like above.( Like a tree grid)

Parent Record I have displayed in the table. But not sure how to read the child array of object record  and iterate the values in table.  Please Any one help me on this. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
 <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="">
                                <th class="slds-size_3-of-10" scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Name</div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="slds-size_3-of-10" scope="col">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Phone</div>
                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <template for:each={studentdata} for:item="stu" for:index="index">
                            <tbody key={stu.key}>
                                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                    <td class="slds-size_3-of-10" data-label="Prospecting">
                                        <div title="Prospecting">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="FirstName">{stu.Name}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="slds-size_3-of-10" data-label="Prospecting">
                                        <div title="Prospecting">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="LastName">{stu.Phone}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>

                           <template for:each={studentdata} for:item="cont" for:index="index">
                            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" key={cont.Id}>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="">
                                        <th class="slds-size_3-of-10" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">FirstName</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="slds-size_3-of-10" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">LastName</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="slds-size_3-of-10" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Phone</div>
                                        </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                            <td class="slds-size_3-of-10" data-label="Prospecting">
                                                <div title="Prospecting">
                                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="FirstName">{cont.FirstName}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="slds-size_3-of-10" data-label="Prospecting">
                                                <div title="Prospecting">
                                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="FirstName">{cont.LastName}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="slds-size_3-of-10" data-label="Prospecting">
                                                <div title="Prospecting">
                                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="FirstName">{cont.Phone}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                </table>
                           </template>
                        </template>
                    </table>
```

**Js:**

```
  @track studenterror;
 @track studentdata;
 @wire(getStudentdetails, { enrollmentName: "$recordId" })
 getstudents(response1) {
this.wiredStudentDataRefresh = response1;
const studentData = response1.data;
const studentError = response1.error;

if (studentData) {
  console.log(studentData);
  let accountList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(studentData));
  console.log(accountList);

  this.studentdata = studentData;
} else if (studentError) {
  this.studenterror = studentError;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
return [SELECT Id, Name , Phone, (Select Id ,FirstName, LastName, Phone from Contacts) from Account];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have additional issues that need to be addressed, but basically you need to iterate over the Contacts within the first iteration:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template for:each="{studentdata}" for:item="stu" for:index="index">
      <tr key={stu.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
        ...
      </tr>
      <template for:each="{stu.Contacts}" for:item="cont">
        <tr key={cont.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
          ...
        </tr>
      </template>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```